# kotlin jvmname ignored by Gradle?

Tags: android, jvm, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am building an Android app and trying to compile a piece of kotlin code with Gradle for it. I have `@JvmName`, but it seems that the annotation is being ignored, thus the compilation fails.

```
@JvmName("setOptionsForPairs")
private fun setOptionsFor(field: JSONObject, options: MutableList<Pair<Int, String>>, spinner: Spinner?){
    options.plusAssign(json2pairs(field.getJSONObject("options")))
    setOptions(options.map { it.second }, spinner)
}

private fun setOptionsFor(field: JSONObject, options: MutableList<String>, spinner: Spinner?){
    val candidates = field.getJSONArray("options")
    for (i in 0..candidates.length() - 1) options.add(candidates.getString(i))
    setOptions(options, spinner)
}
```

Gradle tells me: Platform declaration clash due to the signatures of above functions.
What am I missing? Should I tell Gradle to explicitly take care of annotations or something else?

As suggested by @Ilya, I created below minimal complete example. This code DOES compile.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val dogs = mutableListOf(Dog("John"), Dog("Betty"))
        val people = mutableListOf(Person("Tom"), Person("Karo"))

        greet(dogs)
        greet(people)
    }

    @JvmName("greetPeople")
    private fun greet(people: MutableList<Person>) {
        print("Hello ${people.map { it.name }.joinToString(",")}")
    }

    private fun greet(people: MutableList<Dog>) {
        print("Hello ${people.map { it.name }.joinToString(",")}")
    }
}

data class Person(val name: String)

data class Dog(val name: String)
```

I checked also if min SDK version might be causing problem, but for the minimal complete example, I use the same min SDK version of 21 and that compiles.I removed `private` from the function names, then that compiles with the `@JvmName` annotation.

Comment: Have you tried clean build?

Comment: @miensol I cleared the cache from Android Studio: File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart. Do you mean this by clean build? It did not work...

Comment: Could you craft a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?
I've tested it with the latest kotlin gradle plugin (1.0.2) and it works fine.

Comment: For the time being I named the functions in two unique names, though it does not look really great.

Comment: @Ilya I have the same issue. It seems to be related to functions which are placed at file-level (not associated to a class or object). When I place these functions with the `@JvmName` annotations into an object compilation works. Also, the functions are `private` within the file. Not sure if that's important. Kotlin version 1.0.3.